# C# in method, have a @ before parameter

Tags: c#, methods, parameters

I met a method in C#

```
int Func(Contact @group)
{
    group.Name = "";
}
```

What dose the '@' mean ?

Comment: "@" enables the use of keywords as identifiers

Comment: Presumably your second line should read `@group.Name = "";`

Answer (score 7):

It's used to escape keywords so you can have parameters named `@class` or similar, which would otherwise result in a syntax error.

See the relevant portion of the specification: [2.4.2 Identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> The prefix "@" enables the use of keywords as identifiers, which is useful when interfacing with other programming languages. The character @ is not actually part of the identifier, so the identifier might be seen in other languages as a normal identifier, without the prefix. An identifier with an @ prefix is called a verbatim identifier. Use of the @ prefix for identifiers that are not keywords is permitted, but strongly discouraged as a matter of style.

Answer (score 3):

I believe it is a literal variable.

Keywords such as `int`, `double`, etc. cannot be used as variable names, however, you can get round this with the `@` symbol:

```
var int = 3; //compile error

var @int = 3; //okay
```